# iPhoneXsシリーズの実機のみLabelが表示されない

Tags: ios, xcode

Swiftであるアプリを開発し、リリースしているのですが、AppStoreからダウンロードしたアプリの一部端末でUILabel(文字)が一切表示されない場合があります

しかし、シュミレーターでは問題なく出力されるのが確認されております。

解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: 他のサイトで問題が解決したのなら、こちらにも内容をフィードバックするようにしてください https://teratail.com/questions/226442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

見えない端末の外観モードがダークモードだったりしませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

書かれている内容だけでは情報が不足していて、誰も**解決策**を提示することはできないでしょう。
なので、この回答も**解決策**ではありません。

こういうとき、問題の原因や解決策を見つけるためには、まず**問題の切り分け**を行う必要があります。

問題の切り分けは問題が起きているプログラムと問題が起きていないプログラムを比べて、何が違うのかを見つけ、違わない部分、つまり問題に関係がない部分を除外する（切り分ける）ことでできます。

今回のケースでは、

- シミュレーターではラベルに文字が表示される
- AppStoreからダウンロードしたアプリの一部端末ではラベルに表示されない

となります。
なので、まず思いつく違いは

- 前者: Debugビルド （おそらく）
- 後者: Releaseビルド

があります。
この場合、 Edit Scheme ( `⌘ <` ) で Build Configuration を **Release** に変更して実行してみたら、シミュレーターでも問題が再現できるかもしれません。
ただし、普通はReleaseビルドで実行したってラベルには文字列はちゃんと表示されます。なので、真の原因は他にあるはずです。

なので、問題が起きる場合と起きない場合、さらに別の違いがないか探す必要があります。

- 端末の画面サイズは同じか

  - 画面サイズが影響している場合、Auto Layoutの指定を疑った方がいいでしょう
- 問題が起きるのはアプリ内のすべてのUILabelか、それとも一部のUILabelか

  - 一部の場合、表示されるラベルとされないラベルの違いは何か
  - 全部の場合、新しいプロジェクトでラベル一つ表示するだけのアプリを作ってみて、それは表示されるか？される場合、違いは何か
- UILabel以外のUIButtonなどは表示されるか
- ダークモードの状態はどうか

  - 文字と背景のどちらかが固定の色で、他方がモード依存の色だと文字と背景が同じ色になってしまうかも
- iOSのバージョンは同じか
- その他、アプリを一旦削除してから再インストールした場合はどうか

などなど。
色々試してみてください。

あと、App Storeに公開する前に、TestFlightで動作確認してみることをおすすめします。App Storeからダウンロードするのと同じ状態のアプリを事前に確認することができます。